# How can I create HTML pages that automatically adjust their images to different mobile screen sizes?

Tags: android, html, mobile

I want to create some HTML pages which will be displayed on different mobile devices. I want them to automatically adjust to different mobile screen sizes.

The HTML pages include text and images. The images may be bigger than 600x450, but if the mobile screen is (for example) 280x320 then the images should automatically adjust their size to fit.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use percentages for sizes instead of PX?

Comment: no i am asking for Html page to show in android based smart phone

Comment: Webviews will automatically adjust the HTML pages to fit in its bounds.

Comment: @Ekansh: you are going to display that in webview? if so no worries about the html page.

Comment: i am showing that html pages in smart phone application not in webview

Comment: @Ekansh: a [webview](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/webview/info) is a component of a smart phone application, used to display HTML pages within the application.

Comment: ok thanx for information i thought webview is web browser of mobile, actually i am web developer and want to create such HTML pages that will auto adjustable in different mobile screens

Comment: @Ekansh: You're welcome. No, web browsers are thankfully still called web browsers even when they run on mobile phones.

Comment: .........................:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the pages you're talking about literally just contain text and images, then I think all you need to do in each HTML page is this:

1. Add this [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) inside the `<head>` tag:

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   ```

   This should make the page render at a reasonable size.
2. Add this `<style>` tag inside the `<head>` tag:

   ```
   <style>
   img {
       max-width: 100%;
   }
   </style>
   ```

   I *think* this will make sure all images don't render any wider than the app's webview's viewport.

   (If that doesn't work, try `width: 100%;` instead. That'll definitely make all images be as wide as the viewport, and therefore no wider.)

However, your question is a bit too general: we could end up writing a book covering all the possibilities. Could you make it more specific to the code you're actually working on?

Answer (score 3):

This technique is known as fluid or adaptive layout there's a good introduction [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/09/smart-fixes-for-fluid-layouts/)

Comment: Nice article , Seems very Helpfulll

Answer (score 2):

Media queries are the best way to do what you want.

Set up your html and stylesheet as usual, but at the end of your CSS document use something similar to the code below.
You will need to work out the different queries for the different device widths and layouts, but this should get you started.

```
/* iPHONE 3-4 + RETINA PORTRAIT STYLES */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-height: 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Your adjusted CSS goes here */
}

/* iPHONE 3-4 + RETINA LANDSCAPE STYLES */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 480px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Your adjusted CSS goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options here, most far to detailed to talk about in a single question.

There is no 'automatic' way of doing this - it will have to be manually coded. Three options I can think of, which will require more investigation:

1. Use the User-Agent http header to identify the device which is connecting and redirect the user to the required website template.
2. Use JavaScript to do the same as above.
3. Use CSS to control each object's size. You could force each object to be a percent of the overall screen size, rather than a fixed value. CSS also provides a way to specify styles based on a given screen size: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: "Use the User-Agent http header to identify the device which is connecting and redirect the user to the required website template." - No. HTML is designed to lay itself out in viewports of various sizes. If you're doing this, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can use media query to make your layout responsive, means fix to all screen small, medium and large.

for more details you can visit this tutorial - [learn responsive design in easy steps](http://blog.klassicweb.com/learn-responsive-design-in-easy-steps/)