# How to optimize website for different screen resolutions?

Tags: html, css

Should I use different CSS files, or simply do everything in percentage (90% instead of 1000px, for example). But while doing everything in % I can't match the background image of a div, font size, etc.

Can you simply give me a link to a solid explanation on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580695/how-can-i-create-html-pages-that-automatically-adjust-their-images-to-different/14580875#14580875

Comment: are you searching "Responsive Web Design"?

Comment: thank you! searched it on Google and found a solid article! I didn't know how to put the question right

Answer (score 2):

You may use various Media tags in CSS for different screen resolutions. You may use a combination of `em`, `px` and `%`.

Modern browsers also support `rem` or `relative-em`

I would suggest to use a pre-created HTML/CSS template to start with and customize it as per your requirements. Bootstrap is a very common and popular template you may use.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has great documentation with many video tutorials available online. I'm now getting into it myself.

Comment: Can you explain and give an example of how it can solve the OPs Q? Links to this "documentation" you speak of would be nice too!

Comment: Here are a couple of links to videos that are helping me a great deal to get the hang of it.

http://tinyurl.com/oampntj
http://tinyurl.com/pcje9nz
http://tinyurl.com/npwphs2
http://vidinterest.com/playlist/enbeeone3/twitter-bootstrap-video-tutorials#.UizMsRaTM5s
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/?s=bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

i would say to use something like bootstrap as your base css http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ it would help you allot from having to reinvent the wheel